# use curl to download indirect image file

Tags: php, image, curl, download

I am try to download image files from url from the following code, but it doesn't return the right content from the server. The image can be rendered in browser by loading the url or downloaded using curl in shell mode, but not in php execution. In php execution, the header's content type returned from the server is '`text/html`' instead of '`image/jpeg`' which it supposes to be.

Anyone has any ideas about this?

```
$url = 'http://count.koubei.com/showphone/showphone.php?f=jpg&w=104&h=10&bc=255,255,255&fc=0,0,0&fs=10&fn=arial&phone=LTIxMDM3MjIyOTc%3D%23dWBzmKEZpTh7YcWvOw%3D%3D';
$file_handler = fopen('phone.jpeg', 'w');
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file_handler);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
fclose($file_handler);
```

Comment: I just tested your code and the image downloaded correctly.

Comment: can the image file be correctly opened. on my mac, the downloaded size of the file is only 20 bytes, which is not the original size.

Comment: I opened it and it was just as if I opened it on the browser. Perhaps its a curl configuration problem of some sort.

Comment: Make sure you have allow_url_fopen enabled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why not just use file_get_contents 
like this

```
$img = file_get_contents("http://count.koubei.com/showphone/showphone.php?f=jpg&w=104&h=10&bc=255,255,255&fc=0,0,0&fs=10&fn=arial&phone=LTIxMDM3MjIyOTc%3D%23dWBzmKEZpTh7YcWvOw%3D%3D");
file_put_contents("photo.jpg",$img);
```

Comment: This only works if your server allows `url_fopen` (I tihnk that's the name of the ini directive).

Comment: The configuration name is `allow_url_fopen` :)

Comment: enabling allow_url_fopen wont be security problem!!?