# Downloading an Image From an External URL With cURL

Tags: php, curl

How do I download an external image off a url with cURL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898711/use-curl-to-download-indirect-image-file

Comment: Any reason why would you choose cURL over file_get_contents() ?

Comment: I am not sure that I will have fopen enabled on my server, so I am avoiding using file_get_contents().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here:

http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/php/php-save-images-using-curl/

```
function save_image($img,$fullpath){
 $ch = curl_init ($img);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
 $rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);
 if(file_exists($fullpath)){
  unlink($fullpath);
 }
 $fp = fopen($fullpath,'x');
 fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
 fclose($fp);
}
```

Other articles/sources:

http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=371632

http://www.bitrepository.com/download-image.html

http://php.bigresource.com/Track/php-Jjg3DsKY/

Answer (score 0):

from php.net - also reads into a string.

```
   <?php
        // create curl resource
        $ch = curl_init();

        // set url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");

        //return the transfer as a string
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        // $output contains the output string
        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        // close curl resource to free up system resources
        curl_close($ch);     
?>
```