# https and images from another site. How to remove warnings for http images using php or javascript without modifying .htaccess file?

Tags: php, image, http, https, warnings

I have an ssl certificate on my web-site. Once images are loaded on the page from another site, it causes warnings kind of "*the page contains both secure and nonsecure items*", so you have to press OK or you see "broken" ssl connection in the browser. One of the ways to escape that warnings is to use http page instead of https, correct?

But, as far as I know, there is another way to exclude that warnings using php or just using javascript. I believe the images are loaded to the temporary folder on my server and are loaded as https images at the same time.
Could anybody tell me the best way to do that? 
Browsing the forum didn't help me a lot.
Thank you.

So, 
how to load

```
<?php echo '<img src="http://www.not_my_site.com/image.jpg" alt="">'; ?>
```

with no warnings on my page `https://my_site.com/index.php` ?

Comment: well, if you don't need to dynamically load the images I guess that the simplest solution will be to save these images on your server and read it from there.

Comment: Yes, that's a good solution, I was thinking about that. But, this way you have to load them manually first (save-> choose a folder). If it happens once in a while, that's a deal. But, if it happens more often... Anyway, I've heard there is a solution I've asked about. If I don't find it, your suggestion would be the last option and just fine. Many thanks.

Comment: @Haradzieniec see my example, I've further clarified the process.

Comment: It is still not clear for me, I'm sorry... index.php contains: <?php echo '<a href="https:// my_site.com/external.php?resource=http:// www.not_my_site.com/image.jpg" alt="">'; ?> ___and___ external.php is in the root folder as well. What's in external.php? "You will have to write the external.php script to make the request on the client's behalf, and then return the content over your existing SSL connection." is not clear for me... Sorry about that.

Comment: This warning is not there for the _generator_ of the webpage, and it's there for _those browsing_ and it's there for a reason: users can assume that when they visit a HTTPS page that the context is SSL encrypted and therefore not subject to snooping.  If you fetch non-encrypted resources then this assumption is false and they deserve to be warned.  The real way to avoid this warning is to use only HTTPS streams on your page

Answer (score 3):

You cannot surpress the error as it's a browser thing.

The only way would be to wrap those calls using an https call on your site.   Something like:

```
<?php echo '<a href="https://my_site.com/external.php?resource=http://www.not_my_site.com/image.jpg" alt="">'; ?>
```

You will have to write the external.php script to make the request on the client's behalf, and then return the content over your existing SSL connection.  **You only NEED to do this for external HTTP-only resources.**

The process would work as follows:

1. The end user's web browser makes an HTTPS request to your external.php script.
2. Check for a saved copy of the resource.  If you've got it cached then skip to step 6, returning the cached resource.
3. Your server forwards on the call to the HTTP resource specified as the `resource`.
4. The remote server responds to the request.
5. Save a copy of the resource for caching.
6. Your web server external.php script then returns that response over the SSL connection.

The web browser only makes 1 request, your web server just has to make an additional one.

This is the only way you'll be able to get rid of the message.

---

Looks even simpler to retrieve the image:  [use curl to download indirect image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898711/use-curl-to-download-indirect-image-file)

Comment: you're suggesting to generate two http/s calls for every image ?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Unfortunately, it is still not clear... OK, you have index.php. It wants to load image.jpg from another site with no warning. What code does external.php contain? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It happens cause your making non-secure (HTTP) calls from a secured-page (HTTPS).

try changing your code to:

```
<?php echo '<a href="https://www.not_my_site.com/image.jpg" alt="">'; ?>
```

Comment: That won't work, as there is no guarantee that the external source responds to HTTPS requests.

Comment: @twilson You meant to say: it MIGHT not work in case "not my site" doesn't support secure requests.

Comment: Semantics, but yes I suppose that would have been a better response.

Comment: Yes, I've just tried a web-site named (it does not matter).. and http is OK, image loads, but once you've tried https, it says: Service Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request. Please try again later.

Comment: if "not your site" does not support secure calls I'm afraid there's no way around it (you'll have to download the images to your server): http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2011/06/trying-to-end-mixed-scripting.html

Comment: Re: "you'll have to download the images to your server": remember the copyright implications of this. Check any licensing of this content, otherwise you or your hosting provider might get a takedown notice from the content owner

Comment: Isn't that the same Copyright question as to "download the images to your server" and "display them directly as <img src=""> from another web-site on you page? (sorry for off topic, but that's a remark regarding the remark).

Comment: @Haradzieniec you know, I wonder: displaying the file in your website using a link to an external server does not create copyrights problems ? I'm pretty sure it does - unless you add some kind of text next to it that credits the source/author - and even then I'm not sure if its totally legit.