# capturing JavaScript included website content with PHP

Tags: curl, web-crawler, web-scraping

I use cURL for all my web-scraping, but I have one problem with my new project. I want to get a picture from a website which is loaded by JS so cURL can't help me with that, I think. So any ideas how to grab a picture with PHP?

Comment: Query the javascript with curl to get the image information

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear *exactly* what you need, so I'll reply to both possible issues.

1) If *downloading* the image is the issue, then [this stack-o question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898711/use-curl-to-download-indirect-image-file) looks useful.

2) If *determining the URI*, etcetera, is the issue, then an easy method is to use the "inspection" panel that's available in any major browser, from which you can view how each portion of the page is retrieved. [This blog post](http://blog.scrapy.org/scraping-ajax-sites-with-scrapy) from the scrapy framework will provide some useful info.