# Download a XLSX file from an indirect link using PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'd like to be able to download the following file to my server using PHP:

https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/b5e7488e117749c19881cce45db13f7e/data

The problem is that it is not a direct link to the file and to remedy this I've tried to use curl but I haven't been succesful. Any suggestions? I've tried using the following curl snippet:

[use curl to download indirect image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898711/use-curl-to-download-indirect-image-file)

However, the output was an empty XLSX file.

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

The quoted example deals with a regular, non-ssl endpoint and omits the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option to allow curl to follow redirects. The following should work OK to download the file - you'll need to download a copy of `cacert.pem` and edit the curl function where shown.

```
<?php

    $url='https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/b5e7488e117749c19881cce45db13f7e/data';
    $target=__DIR__ . '/covid-19.xlsx';

    $hndl=fopen( $target, 'w' );
    $options=array(
        CURLOPT_FILE    =>  $hndl
    );

    $res=curl( $url, $options );
    if( $res->info->http_code==200 && file_exists( $target ) )echo 'ok';
    fclose( $hndl );





    function curl( $url=NULL, $options=NULL ){
        /*
            Edit this to suit your environment. 
            Download a copy from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
        */
        $cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem';
        $curl=curl_init();
        if( parse_url( $url,PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
        }
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL,trim( $url ) );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla the Gorilla' );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' );
        if( isset( $options ) && is_array( $options ) ){
            foreach( $options as $param => $value ) curl_setopt( $curl, $param, $value );
        }
        $res=(object)array(
            'response'  =>  curl_exec( $curl ),
            'info'      =>  (object)curl_getinfo( $curl ),
            'errors'    =>  curl_error( $curl )
        );
        curl_close( $curl );
        return $res;
    }
?>
```